Cloud Firestore: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Missing or insufficient permissions.")
I have a cloud function associated with a service account: xxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com, which has Editor and Owner permissions. I have also tried assigning this account varying other permissions including datastore.owner and datastore.editor.
I have also changed my firebase rules around, including making it open (temporarily) for testing purposes
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore { 
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} { 
      allow read, write; 
    } 
  } 
}

And setting simple authorization rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow admins to read and write all documents
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if hasAnyRole(["ADMIN", "OWNER"]);
    }

    function hasAnyRole(roles) {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    }
}

My cloud function itself is very simple, and is just adding an array of day values to the "days" field in the document:
        public async Task HandleAsync(CloudEvent cloudEvent, DocumentEventData data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the recently-written value. This expression will result in a null value
            // if any of the following is true:
            // - The event doesn't contain a "new" document
            // - The value doesn't contain a field called "frequency"
            // - The "frequency" field isn't a string
            string currentFreqValue = data.Value?.ConvertFields().GetValueOrDefault("frequency") as string;
            if (currentFreqValue is null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"Event did not contain a suitable document");
                return;
            }

            ArrayList daysArrayList = GetDays(currentFreqValue);

            // The CloudEvent subject is "documents/x/y/...".
            // The Firestore SDK FirestoreDb.Document method expects a reference relative to
            // "documents" (so just the "x/y/..." part). This may be simplified over time.
            if (cloudEvent.Subject is null || !cloudEvent.Subject.StartsWith("documents/"))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("CloudEvent subject is not a document reference.");
            }

            // Get the document path so we can update the days field
            string documentPath = cloudEvent.Subject.Substring("documents/".Length);

            await _firestoreDb.Document(documentPath).UpdateAsync("days", daysArrayList);

            _logger.LogInformation($"Current Value of frequency field is: {currentFreqValue}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Days correspond to: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(GetDays(currentFreqValue))}");
            return;
        }

Yet, my permission error persists. This is driving me a little bonkers at this point, and I'm not sure why I am still getting this error even with public rules set. Any thoughts?


I assume the Cloud Function and the Firestore database are in the same project. Where do you initialize the Cloud Firestore client? Client library requests aren't filtered through security rules. So your security rules are not relevant to this issue.

Cloud Functions use a service account, so access the database without having to adhere to the security rules. Whatever is causing this, the security are not it.

@DazWilkin thank you for mentioning the initialization of the Cloud Firestore client, this was my issue. I was initializing the client with the wrong projectId. Sometimes its the simplest of things!
